# Use NSArray in SQLite Statement

Tags: objective-c, sqlite, swift, sqlite.swift

I use [SQLite.swift](https://github.com/stephencelis/SQLite.swift) and want to replace the question marks in a statement. This can be done for single entries like this:

```
let stmt = db.prepare("INSERT INTO users (email) VALUES (?)")
for email in ["betty@icloud.com", "cathy@icloud.com"] {
    stmt.run(email)
}
```

I did not see how I can do the following to use a array like:

```
var values:[String] = ["test1","test2", "test3"]
```

in a Statement like:

```
let stmt = db.prepare("SELECT * from users where email in (?)")
```

The following does not work:

```
stmt.run(values)
```

**How do I use an NSArray as an argument for a statement?**

Comment: how about

`for email in values {
  stmt.run(email)
}`

Sorry if I misinterpret your question....

Comment: @deanware Won't this generate one query for each Array entry?

Comment: ahh yes...your right...this is not what your looking for....sorry...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using the type-safe layer, you can use `contains()`:

```
users.filter(contains(["test1", "test2"], email))

// the above assumes this boilerplate precedes it:
let email = Expression<String>("email")
let users = db["users"]
```

If you're using the raw SQLite3 API, it does not support arrays, so you'll need to format those yourself:

```
let emails = ["test1", "test2"]
let template = join(", ", [String](count: count(emails), repeatedValue: "?"))
let stmt = db.prepare(
    "SELECT * FROM users WHERE email IN (\(template))", emails
)
```

Comment: Why is the last ``, emails`` ? What does this mean?

Comment: It's defined immediately above it. `template` basically expands the number of `emails` to the number of needed `?`s, in this case `?, ?`. This basically makes the following: `db.prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE email IN (?, ?)", ["test1", "test2"])`